# Not able to successfully run HelloWorld app on HANA Cloud from Eclipse

Tags: java, servlets, hana, sap-business-technology-platform

Software components:

- Java version 8.x
- Apache Tomcat version 8.x
- J2EE 2.5 (Deployment Descriptor) used in WebApplication

[image]

- HANA Cloud trial configured and validated correctly in eclipse.

  [image]
- WebApplication to print 'Hello World!' created exactly same as mentioned in the documentation of HANA help, where URL pattern for servlet is changed to  - '/', I have made it exactly the same.

  [image]
- Application URL is getting generated in SAP HANA Cockpit after I start the application on server.

  [image]

Error while I try to run servlet on HANA cloud server from eclipse:

> while trying to invoke the method com.sap.core.tools.eclipse.server.common.runtime.ISapSdkRuntime.getRuntimeSdkId() of a null object loaded from local variable 'sdkRuntimeDelegate'

When I click on the Application URL nothing is being shown in the page.

If any solution you can provide to correct this or any improvements that you feel.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Hi Roshan, can you please show me the content of your web.xml file?

Comment: It is solved now, there was a problem of J2EE runtime, I had to setup JAVA Web Tomcat 7 runtime and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It is solved now, there was a problem of J2EE runtime, I had to setup JAVA Web Tomcat 7 runtime and it worked